# A problem with audio_manage Package on my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I try To make a music app and I used the audio_manager package to run a music file the app closed after click play.
I need help with that.

the initial player manager :
`final OnAudioQuery _audioQuery = new OnAudioQuery();`

and the audio file is an external audio file :

```
onTap: () {
        print("${song.data}");
        cubit.audioManager.start("file://${song.uri}", "title", desc: "desc", cover: "assets/image/noaudio.png").catchError((error) {print("error${error}");});
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android then add targetsdk version to 30.